# Accessing Ruby Hash value using a string

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

I have a ruby array like below

```
tomcats = [
  'sandbox',
  'sandbox_acserver',
  'sandbox_vgw'
]
```

I need to pass the string as a hash index like below

```
tomcats.each do |tomcat_name|
  obi_tomcat '#{tomcat_name}' do
    Chef::Log::info("Creating tomcat instance - #{tomcat_name}")
    Chef::Log::info("#{node['obi']['tomcat']['sandbox'][:name]}") // works
    Chef::Log::info("#{node['obi']['tomcat']['#{tomcat_name}'][:name]}") // doesn't work
  end
end
```

The last log throws an error since the access with `#{tomcat_name}` is `nil`. I'm new to ruby. How do I access with key as the `tomcat_name` ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In normal code, you'd write:

```
node['obi']['tomcat'][tomcat_name][:name]
```

In a string interpolation (useless here, because it's the only thing in the string in this case), it is completely the same:

```
"#{node['obi']['tomcat'][tomcat_name][:name]}"
```

Comment: So basically, calling `Chef::Log::info(node['obi']['tomcat'][tomcat_name][:name])` should work!

Comment: Yup. You only need interpolation if you want to insert stuff in a bigger string, like in your first `info` line - `"#{foo}"` is same as `foo`, but `"Big #{foo}!"` is same as `"Big " + foo + "!"`, which is not as readable.

Comment: This one may be more useless in this case, but it still work: `"#{node['obi']['tomcat']["#{tomcat_name}"][:name]}"`

Answer (score 2):

`#{}` only works in double quote, as `"#{tomcat_name}"`.

But you don't need the syntax here, just use `[tomcat_name]` directly.

Answer (score 0):

When I saw this question, I'm thinking whether ruby placeholder could be put inside other placeholder in string interpolation. And I found that ruby actually support it, and most interesting thing is that you don't need to escape the `"` inside the string.

Although it is not very useful in this case, it still works if you write as below:

```
Chef::Log::info("#{node['obi']['tomcat']["#{tomcat_name}"][:name]}")
```

Below is an simple example of placeholder inside other placeholder:

```
tomcats = [
  'sandbox',
  'sandbox_acserver',
  'sandbox_vgw'
]

node = {
    'sandbox_name' => "sandbox name",
    'sandbox_acserver_name' => "sandbox_acserver name",
    'sandbox_vgw_name' => "sandbox_vgw name",
}

tomcats.each do | tomcat |
    puts "This is tomcat : #{node["#{tomcat}_name"]}"
end
```